# Difference between .NET Core 1.1.1 and 1.0.4 versions

Tags: .net, .net-core

There are two version of .NET Core framework released at [core github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases). Question is what is the difference between these releases 1.1.1 and 1.0.4 and why they are released at same time?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/versions/lts-current

Comment: Why are there two versions of *any* piece of software? There's an original version, and then there's an improved version. The original is still being provided because people still use it, and the new version very likely has breaking changes (which is what motivated the version number increment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the versions of **.net core** releases. **.NET Core 1.0** is the initial release which is later replaced with major release of **.NET core 1.1**.

Microsoft encourage us to use .NET Core 1.1 since it has more reach and improvement than .NET Core 1.0. It is pointless to write what is been improved here since Microsoft has already listed in their [core documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/core).

Having said, Microsoft doesn't want to disappoint folks who already has .NET Core 1.0 in place for their work and hence they still support .Net Core 1.0. I am not sure how long they support this side by side versions. But it is worth considering new version since there is a good reason for it. Therefore, I propose you to move on to .NET Core 1.1 if possible or use it for all of your new projects.

Now if you want to look at the current releases;

1. **.NET Core 1.0** is on release **1.0.4**
2. **.NET Core 1.1** is on release **1.1.1**

[Released versions](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases)

Let me list you a quick comparison which I think is easy to understand:

1. One major change targeting these framework is project format and build engine:

   1.1 **.NET Core 1.0** support **project.json** with custom build engine, which
   contained all metadata, dependencies and tools for compile/build projects.

   1.2 **.NET Core 1.1** on the other hand support **.csproj**  (the old and familiar type) with MSBuild/XUnit and tools for compile/build projects.
2. .NET Core 1.1 has huge **performance improvement** than .NET Core 1.0. See the  [comparison](https://www.techempower.com/blog/2016/11/16/framework-benchmarks-round-13/)

Comment: Thanks, I don't see this information in a simple way in documentation.

Comment: For support timelines, see: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/support. TLDR: both 1.0 and 1.1 will EOL on the same date.

Comment: Your coments on `project.json` vs `csproj` are wrong. The latest updates of 1.0 and 1.1 both support `csproj`.

Comment: That techempower article is seriously misleading. Please read it carefully before citing it: "The degree of improvement is absolutely astonishing, going from 2,120 requests per second on Mono in Round 11 to 1,822,366 requests per second on ASP.NET Core in Round 13". They are not comparing 1.0 with 1.1.